How can I custom sort a list column using another list column?
I have a table
| user     | list_1   | list_2   | list_3   |  rank   |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |-------- |
|   xxx    |  [1,3,5] |  [8,3,5] |  [6,7,8] | [1,2,3] |
|   yyy    |  [4,9,5] |  [3,4,5] |  [7,8,3] | [1,3,2] |
|   zzz    |  [4,6,1] |  [9,3,6] |  [4,3,2] | [2,3,1] |

The column rank is derived from the rank of the column list_1
I would like to sort the rest of the columns list_2, list_3 using the rank column.
The desired output should be
| user | list_1  | list_2  | list_3  |  rank   |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| xxx  | [1,3,5] | [8,3,5] | [6,7,8] | [1,2,3] |
| yyy  | [4,5,9] | [3,5,4] | [7,3,8] | [1,3,2] |
| zzz  | [1,4,6] | [6,9,3] | [2,4,3] | [2,3,1] |


i have tried various .list functions, but I think they cannot take in arguments by row
Is there any function in polars that can do this? Much appreciated
import polars as pl

data = {
    "user": ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"],
    "list_1": [[1, 3, 5], [4, 9, 5], [4, 6, 1]],
    "list_2": [[8, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5], [9, 3, 6]],
    "list_3": [[6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 3], [4, 3, 2]],
    "rank": [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 1]]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

print(df)


There is something off with your example, either the rank of zzz is incorrect, or your output is

Alternative to the solution using an explode(), group_by(), agg() pattern, one can leverage pl.Expr.list.gather to select the elements from each list in order.
For this, we transform the ranks using pl.Expr.list.eval and pl.Expr.arg_sort to obtain a list of indices selecting the elements in the order suggested by rank.
cols = ["list_1", "list_2", "list_3"]

df.with_columns(
    pl.col(cols).list.gather(
        pl.col("rank").list.eval(pl.element().arg_sort())
    )
)

shape: (3, 5)
┌──────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ user ┆ list_1    ┆ list_2    ┆ list_3    ┆ rank      │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ xxx  ┆ [1, 3, 5] ┆ [8, 3, 5] ┆ [6, 7, 8] ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ yyy  ┆ [4, 5, 9] ┆ [3, 5, 4] ┆ [7, 3, 8] ┆ [1, 3, 2] │
│ zzz  ┆ [1, 4, 6] ┆ [6, 9, 3] ┆ [2, 4, 3] ┆ [2, 3, 1] │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


Nice one, I'd probably change it to pl.col("rank").list.eval(pl.element() - 1 instead though. Just feels more neat to me. arg_sort() would work on current example, but it also would work, for example, on rank = [-100, 100, 200] instead of [1,2,3] which, I'd say, not the intention.

@RomanPekar True.. I actually had pl.element() - 1 locally first, but switched to the more general solution. However, just decrementing the rank is likely also much more efficient. I'll edit the answer to mention the alternative as soon as I am no longer on mobile.

polars
You could explode, sort by group of users, then aggregate back to lists:
df = pl.DataFrame({'user': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'],
                   'list_1': [[1, 3, 5], [4, 9, 5], [4, 6, 1]],
                   'list_2': [[8, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5], [9, 3, 6]],
                   'list_3': [[6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 3], [4, 3, 2]],
                   'rank': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 1]]})

cols = ['list_1', 'list_2', 'list_3', 'rank']

rank = df['rank']

out = (df.explode(cols).select(pl.all().sort_by('rank').over('user'))
         .group_by('user', maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col(cols))
         .with_columns(rank=rank)
      )

Output:
┌──────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ user ┆ list_1    ┆ list_2    ┆ list_3    ┆ rank      │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ xxx  ┆ [1, 3, 5] ┆ [8, 3, 5] ┆ [6, 7, 8] ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ yyy  ┆ [4, 5, 9] ┆ [3, 5, 4] ┆ [7, 3, 8] ┆ [1, 3, 2] │
│ zzz  ┆ [1, 4, 6] ┆ [6, 9, 3] ┆ [2, 4, 3] ┆ [2, 3, 1] │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


original answer
pure python
Assuming python lists, you have to iterate over them and reorder:
cols = ['list_1', 'list_2', 'list_3']

for c in cols:
    df[c] = [[l[i-1] for i in r] for l, r in zip(df[c], df['rank'])]

Output:
 user     list_1     list_2     list_3       rank
0  xxx  [1, 3, 5]  [8, 3, 5]  [6, 7, 8]  [1, 2, 3]
1  yyy  [4, 5, 9]  [3, 5, 4]  [7, 3, 8]  [1, 3, 2]
2  zzz  [6, 1, 4]  [3, 6, 9]  [3, 2, 4]  [2, 3, 1]

Note that the ranks seems incorrect in your example. If you need to compute the rank:
cols = ['list_1', 'list_2', 'list_3']

df['rank'] = [(np.argsort(x)+1).tolist() for x in df['list_1']]

for c in cols:
    df[c] = [[l[i-1] for i in r] for l, r in zip(df[c], df['rank'])]

Output:
  user     list_1     list_2     list_3       rank
0  xxx  [1, 3, 5]  [8, 3, 5]  [6, 7, 8]  [1, 2, 3]
1  yyy  [4, 5, 9]  [3, 5, 4]  [7, 3, 8]  [1, 3, 2]
2  zzz  [1, 4, 6]  [6, 9, 3]  [2, 4, 3]  [3, 1, 2]

numpy
If all your list have the same size, you could also use an intermediate 3D numpy array, argsort and take_along_axis:
a = np.array(df[cols].to_numpy().tolist())
order = np.argsort(a[:, 0], axis=1)
df['rank'] = (order+1).tolist()
df[cols] = np.take_along_axis(a, a[:, [0]].argsort(axis=-1), axis=-1).tolist()

Output:
  user     list_1     list_2     list_3       rank
0  xxx  [1, 3, 5]  [8, 3, 5]  [6, 7, 8]  [1, 2, 3]
1  yyy  [4, 5, 9]  [3, 5, 4]  [7, 3, 8]  [1, 3, 2]
2  zzz  [1, 4, 6]  [6, 9, 3]  [2, 4, 3]  [3, 1, 2]


I guess your solution works for pandas, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this in polars, without having to convert to pandas to do this

@benedictine_cumbersome Oops, sorry, I missed the polars tag; Can you provide a [mre] as code?

I'm pretty new to this. Is the above dataframe considered a MRE?

@benedictine_cumbersome yes thanks, I updated my answer. Also I'd recommend to post the polars text output, that makes it immediately clear that you are using polars ;)

the polars section worked! Thank you very much

If you adjust your rank calculation a bit so it' 0-based

list.eval() to iterate through list elements.
rank() to calculate rank.

df = df.with_columns(
    rank = pl.col.list_1.list.eval(pl.element().rank().cast(pl.Int32) - 1)
)

┌──────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ user ┆ list_1    ┆ list_2    ┆ list_3    ┆ rank      │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i32] │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ xxx  ┆ [1, 3, 5] ┆ [8, 3, 5] ┆ [6, 7, 8] ┆ [0, 1, 2] │
│ yyy  ┆ [4, 9, 5] ┆ [3, 4, 5] ┆ [7, 8, 3] ┆ [0, 2, 1] │
│ zzz  ┆ [4, 6, 1] ┆ [9, 3, 6] ┆ [4, 3, 2] ┆ [1, 2, 0] │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


list.gather() to reposition elements according to indices in rank column.

cols = ["list_1", "list_2", "list_3"]

df.with_columns(
    pl.col(cols).list.gather(pl.col.rank)
)

┌──────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ user ┆ list_1    ┆ list_2    ┆ list_3    ┆ rank      │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i32] │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ xxx  ┆ [1, 3, 5] ┆ [8, 3, 5] ┆ [6, 7, 8] ┆ [0, 1, 2] │
│ yyy  ┆ [4, 5, 9] ┆ [3, 5, 4] ┆ [7, 3, 8] ┆ [0, 2, 1] │
│ zzz  ┆ [6, 1, 4] ┆ [3, 6, 9] ┆ [3, 2, 4] ┆ [1, 2, 0] │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

Alternatively, you can adjust existing rank data and work with your original dataframe:
df.with_columns(
    pl.col(cols).list.gather(
        pl.col("rank").list.eval(pl.element() - 1)
    )
)

┌──────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ user ┆ list_1    ┆ list_2    ┆ list_3    ┆ rank      │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ xxx  ┆ [1, 3, 5] ┆ [8, 3, 5] ┆ [6, 7, 8] ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ yyy  ┆ [4, 5, 9] ┆ [3, 5, 4] ┆ [7, 3, 8] ┆ [1, 3, 2] │
│ zzz  ┆ [6, 1, 4] ┆ [3, 6, 9] ┆ [3, 2, 4] ┆ [2, 3, 1] │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

